# meaning of the notation a belongs to $ C^n[a,b]$

Tags: soft-question

This notation stands for what :
$X$ belongs to $C^n[a,b]$ ?
I think $x$ takes values continuously between $a$ and $b$ in $n$ tuples.

Comment: Does your book not define it?

Comment: I got in a question paper

Comment: I got in a question paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically $C^n[a,b]$ denotes the set of all functions $f$, where $f$ is an $n$-times differentiable continuous function over the interval $[a,b]$.